# White Space appearing when aligning divs with in-line block

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a series of 8 divs I'm aligning horizontally within a parent container.  Each child div is 12.5% so when laid out across the page this will add up to a total of 100% of the parent. The final div is being pushed below the others because there isn't enough room and this seems to be caused by the mystery whitespace on the right-side of each div.

Does anyone know what is causing this whitespace and more importantly, how to remove it?

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.linebox{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    width: 12.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <main id="main-content">
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-1></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-2></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-3></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-4></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-5></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-6></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-7></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-8></div>
  </main>
```

Comment: I'm already using inline-block

Comment: Use flex: https://jsfiddle.net/np1cje5g/

Comment: To add a little bit, the whitespace actually comes from the whitespace in the html. If you put all your linebox elements on one line without any space between them then you wouldn't get any whitespace. I'd still rather go with the flex approach though.

Comment: Thanks @Alex If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  I prefer this to the flexbox solution which obviously has the potentially for other side effect.

Comment: No problem. :) I can't answer though because the question was marked as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options, set the font size to: 0 to remove white space, or your main-content needs to use Flex, for example:

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0; // choose one
  display: flex; // or this...
}

.linebox{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    width: 12.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <main id="main-content">
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-1></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-2></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-3></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-4></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-5></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-6></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-7></div>
      <div class="linebox" id=linebox-8></div>
  </main>
```